# UML Modeling with NoSQL backend?

Tags: nosql, uml

Are there any UML Modeling tools (like Sparx Enterprise Architect) that are able to use a NoSQL backend for storage (like MongoDB, RavenDB, etc)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge the storage of UML tools is:

- Enterprise Architect: Microsoft Access Database
- NoMagic: zipped XML file (XMI)
- ArgoUML: zipped XML File
- Rational Rose: ASCII file in petal format
- Poseidon UML: zipped XML file (XMI)
- [Umbrello](http://uml.sourceforge.net/%3a%20XML%20%28XMI%29%20file): XML file (XMI)

for a more complete list of UML tools see
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unified_Modeling_Language_tools

To my knowledge none of the tools has such a NoSQL backend at this time. Some tools start to have RESTful interface which might be a start for a mapping from UML to NoSQL:

Feel free to edit this article to add more details. My own company BITPlan offers conversion services between these Modelling tools and formats and we could happily supply you with a conversion format between XMI and a NoSQL DB if you stick to a subset of UML. Just send me a personal message if you are interested in details.

Comment: Thanks for that information.  I know Enterprise Architect can also use a MS SQL Server backend.